# What's the alternative to using references (and prepend) for a TypeScript SPA?

Tags: typescript

I have multiple TypeScript libraries checked out into various folders and I combine them into a single .js file for a Single Page Application via project references:

```
"references": [
    {
        "prepend": true,
        "path": "../../Javascript/Loader/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
        "prepend": true,
        "path": "../../Javascript/Stately/tsconfig.json"
    },
    // etc
]
```

Compiler options are as follows:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceRoot": "./src",
    "rootDir": "./src/",
    "outFile": "myGame.js",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true
},
```

With TypeScript 5+, project references with "prepend" set are being deprecated and my development methodology has a risk of becoming obsolete. According to the devs, I have in fact been [doing it wrong all along](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51909#issuecomment-1407009423):

> The functionality is going away entirely. You look into something like rollup, parcel, or just straight concatenation with a script.

> Side observation: to be honest, using prepend with system+outFile was never even considered as a scenario when that feature was implemented, so the fact that worked in the first place is kind of a happy accident at best

What might be the best approach going forwards to be able to combine multiple TypeScript projects into a single .js file for SPAs?

Comment: You quoted the answer: "You look into something like rollup, parcel, or just straight concatenation with a script."

Comment: True, but I wondered what standard practise was - is there a best approach in this scenario?

Comment: Webpack and Vite are popular options